# Do we need a [characterization] tag or redirect?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

I was writing a question when I noticed there was no tag for characterization, only "characters", which seems to serve the same purpose. I was thinking this might be a bit confusing because "characterization" is a well-known term within writing and in teaching writing techniques, whereas "characters" is very vague and could be misinterpreted as a number of different things (e.g., character names). People are likely going to search for "characterization" here and not find what they are looking for. This is especially true for newer users who are unlikely to be familiar with the structure of Writing SE.

Is there any way we can rig up a redirect so that "characterization" is treated as a possible synonym of the "characters" tag?

Comment: You should have enough reputation to be able to [suggest a synonym for that tag](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tags/characters/synonyms), and *in theory*, the community will decide whether the synonym is needed by simply voting on the suggestion, without the need for a Meta discussion. However, given that the site's tags seem to be poorly maintained in general, I think a Meta discussion is needed just to draw some extra attention to the suggestion.